# How do i print out a number triangle in python?

Tags: python

How do i print out a number triangle in python using a loop based program? It is not a homework assignment or anything its just an exercise from the book i have been trying to do but have not really come close. The triangle should print out looking like this:

```
1
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Comment: Can you share the buggy code ? Also, why does 5 print 4 times ?

Comment: `print('\n'.join([' '.join([str(i) for _ in range(i)]) for i in range(1,7)]))`

Comment: sorry my mistake, and there is no buggy code i just cant figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(7):
    print (str(i) + " ")*i
```

***output:***

```
1  
2 2  
3 3 3  
4 4 4 4  
5 5 5 5 5  
6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Answer (score 15):

Just thought I would drop this here, even though it actually avoids using nested loops. But uses some elegant algebra.

```
for i in range(1, n):
    print((i*(10**i-1))//9)
```

In essence it is simply because 10^n-1 is n consecutive 9s. I will leave the rest up to you ;-)

Comment: best answer to print triangle without using string manipulation

Comment: HackerRank 101 :)

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty simple to do using a `for` loop.

```
def printTri(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print(str(i)*i)

>>> printTri(6)
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
```

Or if you'd like to have spaces between the numbers

```
def printTri(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print(' '.join(str(i)*i))

>>> printTri(6)
1
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def printTri(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        print("{:^30}".format(' '.join(str(i)*i)))
printTri(6)
```

**Output:**

```
          1               
         2 2              
        3 3 3             
       4 4 4 4            
      5 5 5 5 5           
     6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Comment: I think this is not exactly what was asked, the output is not left aligned.

Answer (score 1):

using `lambda` and `map` function:

```
>>> def triangle(n):
...     print "\n".join(map(lambda x:str(x)*x,range(1,n+1)))
... 
>>> triangle(6)
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
```

if you want space between :

```
>>> def triangle(n):
...     print "\n".join(map(lambda x:(str(x)+' ')*x,range(1,n+1)))
... 
>>> triangle(6)
1 
2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Answer (score 1):

using string manipulation we can use:

```
for i in range(1, n):
    print `i` * n
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "1"
for i in range(1,6):
  print(i * s)
  s = int(s) + 1
  s = str(s)
```

Comment: can you please add more details on your answer?